# JIRA Jql query: merging two jql

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I want to get all the issues in the current sprint. We have two different scrum teams A and B and the sprint name for these teams starts with prefix teamA and teamB respectively. So, I'll have two open sprints at any point of time, one for each team. I'm interested in getting the issues only for team A.
The jql I'm using is:

```
jql=sprint in openSprints() AND sprint="teamA"
```

This doesn't work for me.

On the other hand, if I divide the above jql into two parts, jql1 and jql2 , it works fine for me.

```
jql1=sprint in openSprints()
jql2=sprint="teamA"
```

How can I merge jql1 and jql2 ?

Answer (score 1):

When I've run into odd results with JQL, using a lot of parentheses to force order of operations has sometimes helped. Try

```
jql=((sprint in openSprints()) AND (sprint="teamA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you divided and it works fine, I believe you want to see the result of the both above JQL at the same time. If that's the case, why you are not using the `OR` operation instead of `AND`?

```
jql=sprint in openSprints() OR sprint="teamA"
```

Comment: Switching AND to OR is a good way to check the structure of the query (if the results are still null, there's a structural problem), but I think the original AND is correct, reading the question carefully.